# How to use Symfony validators on an array of items (dates, emails, etc.)?

Tags: symfony1, validation

I have a form where users add dates to a list. I can easily validate a single date, but how do is use sfValidateDate to validate an array/collection of dates?

sfValidateDate returns an error for obvious reasons.

I've experimented with this:

$this->setValidator('dates_list', new sfValidatorSchemaForEach(new sfValidatorDate(),2));

... but I've hardcoded the number 2 as the number of times the validator should repeat. I'm not sure if this is even remotely correct, but it seems to work in practice for 2 dates. However, the user of the form can add any number of dates, so it needs to be dynamic.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `$this->getValues()`? Then you can simply get dates count submitted by user.